# In Retrofit 422 code response I am not getting full error body response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am not getting a full response string as JSON from retrofit 422 code

here is what I got in error body

```
[size=67 text=[{"field":"current_password","message":"Invalid current password…]
```

Thanks

**Update**

```
val listType = object : TypeToken<List<UpdatePasswordError>>() {}.type
                                val errorConverter: Converter<ResponseBody, List<UpdatePasswordError>> = networkClientI.mRetrofit.responseBodyConverter<List<UpdatePasswordError>>(listType, arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0))
                                val errorList = errorConverter.convert(it.errorBody()!!)
```

I have successfully converted my response error body into Json

**UpdatePasswordError.kt**

```
data class UpdatePasswordError(
    @SerializedName("field")
    val `field`: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("message")
    val message: String? = null
```

)

Comment: Try it in postman.

Comment: I have done it already in postman it's giving me full response

Comment: `[
  {
    "field": "current_password",
    "message": "Invalid current password"
  }
]`

Answer (score 0):

Why did you decide that not all the string with an error comes in response? Did you check through Debagger? Try to handle the network error as described here: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling

Comment: Thanks for the help man. I have fixed that by using Converter `val listType = object : TypeToken<List<UpdatePasswordError>>() {}.type
                                    val errorConverter: Converter<ResponseBody, List<UpdatePasswordError>> = networkClientI.mRetrofit.responseBodyConverter<List<UpdatePasswordError>>(listType, arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0))
                                    val errorList = errorConverter.convert(it.errorBody()!!)`